# "Hat Dash" 2013

Tags: discussion, events

Last year, as a promotional effort, Stack Exchange ran an event called "Hat Dash", which almost every site in the Stack Exchange network participated in, where users earned hats for their avatars for performing certain actions on the site.

[image: Hats!]

We don't know what the hats will look like this year, but last year the hats included things like a fedora with a feather pen, for those gifted individuals who fix our posts via editing, and there were other types of hats for other actions. The hats shown above were all from the first year's event.

These hats will likely be somewhat holiday-themed and may even be a bit goofy.

**Details:**

- The event will run from December 16th to January 3th.
- Users can see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/
- People who don't want to participate can "opt-out" and continue to view the site as normal, sans hats. Just click the "I hate hats" option, which will be in the footer of the site during the event. :(
- The only change to PMSE will be the hats on users' avatars, and the infamous "I hate hats" link in the footer.
- We'll let the community management team know that we plan to participate on Wednesday, November 27th, unless there is an overwhelming number of community members who strongly feel such an idea isn't in our best interests.

**So what say you, PMSE community!?  *Do we want hats?* Upvote this post if you do want hats, and downvote if you loathe them.**

---

[image: Top Users page, with hats]

***Screenshot of the [Winterbash Leaderboard](http://winterba.sh) as it looked in 2012.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as we got no answer so far, I'd like to share my opinion and tell that I'd like to have some hats around to make our Christmas a little more interesting.

It was nice last year to see the hats people chose to keep on their avatar, especially those ones with a face picture (as the hat completely fit!).

Still, if there's anyone around who really hate hats, it's still an option to opt out, so I see no harm on jump in.

Comment: It's now official! PMSE will participate in Hat Dash. :)